# Given an array of objects, group them only leaving one record of each object given a property which should contain the lowest value

Tags: javascript

Given the following array

```
[
  {
    balance: 105,
    address: 'dd',
    datetime: 2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    balance: 111,
    address: 'aa',
    datetime: 2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    balance: 115,
    address: 'dd',
    datetime: 2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    balance: 123,
    address: 'aa',
    datetime: 2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    balance: 153,
    address: 'dd',
    datetime: 2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z
  }
]
```

I want this array to end up looking like

```
[
      {
        balance: 105,
        address: 'dd',
        datetime: 2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z
      },
      {
        balance: 111,
        address: 'aa',
        datetime: 2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z
      }
    ]
```

I have tooken the repeated objects based on its address and only left the one with the lowest balance value.

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate the desired objects. For this look for every object if in the accumulated result-object a property with the address-value exists as key. If not create one an add the object as value. Otherwise look if the balance from the current object is smaller and if so update the object.
At last use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the values for the desired array.

```js
function convert(array) {
    return Object.values(array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (!acc[cur.address]) {
            acc[cur.address] = cur;
        } else {
            if (cur.balance <  acc.balance) {
                 acc[cur.address] = cur;
            }
        }
        return acc;
    }, {}));
}

let array = [
  {
    balance: 105,
    address: 'dd',
    datetime: '2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    balance: 111,
    address: 'aa',
    datetime: '2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    balance: 115,
    address: 'dd',
    datetime: '2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    balance: 123,
    address: 'aa',
    datetime: '2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    balance: 153,
    address: 'dd',
    datetime: '2020-08-23T22:00:00.000Z'
  }
];

console.log(convert(array));
```